# How to convert a returned DWORD value in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dll, ctypes, dword

I'm working for the first time with ctypes to import DLLs. The DLL which I've imported contains a function which return a DWORD value.
How can I convert this DWORD value?

for other functions which takes WORD arguments values I tried something like this (found in stack overflow).

```
from ctypes import *
my_dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary (r"C:\\Users\\Mimouni\\Documents\\FFT_python\\Sense2020Dll.dll")
py_DLL_Acquire_Spectrum = my_dll.DLL_Acquire_Spectrum
py_DLL_Acquire_Spectrum.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)]
py_DLL_Acquire_Spectrum.restype = None
pdblWavelength = (c_double)(my_dll.DLL_Get_Pixel_Count()) 
pdblPower = (c_double)(my_dll.DLL_Get_Pixel_Count())
pdblTemperature = (c_double)(0)
py_DLL_Acquire_Spectrum(pdblWavelength,pdblPower,pdblTemperature)
```

How can I use wintypes for returned values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with the above code? Please also post the *C* (header) declarations for the function you are use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable `x` of type `DWORD` (which is just an alias for `ctypes.c_ulong`), you can just use `a.value` to get its `int` value.

Comment: >>> my_dll.DLL_Get_DLL_Version()

>21922080

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have something like this, it's a returned value how can I put .value ?

Comment: if my_dll.DLL_Get_DLL_Version() is function returing the dword value, you just get the value from it. my_dll.DLL_Get_DLL_Version().value